# AWS Lambda - Access resources (EC2) in another AWS account

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

I have an AWS Lambda which is querying EC2 instances in my account, I'll call it account A and its working fine, I can see its finding my servers. I also want the lambda to query EC2 instances in another AWS account at the same time, I'll call that account B - is that possible?

I've got the following policy to allow the lambda to assume the role in account B but it only queried the same servers - all in account A - I'm just wondering if I am missing something?

Here is my policy which I've attached to the lambda role:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Assume Role",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::AccountB:role/MyRoleNameInAccountB"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "ec2:DescribeInstances",
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the Lambda to be able to assume a role in a `AccountB`, the role in `AccountB` has to have a trust policy which needs to allow the Lambda to assume the role.

Also, the role in `AccountB` has to have the policy which allows the Lambda to describe EC2 instances. `AccountB` should be the entity which allows actions inside itself, not the other way around, for obvious security reasons.

Recommend checking out this [AWS support page](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-function-assume-iam-role/).